# How can I disable the "New hardware found" message on Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, notifications

On my netbook I have a Bluetooth device which is not installed – no driver was installed.

Every time I start Windows, a message appears

> New hardware found, do you want to install driver?

Can this message be disabled?

EDIT: I don't use it and I don't want to have it! (security reasons)

Comment: Install the driver. (XP SP2 already has native support for many Bluetooth devices.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every hardware item is listed in the device manager as parent-children node. You can`t disable the parent, so disable the child node and the annoying message will stop showing. Simple :)

Answer (score 4):

Try to use Windows Update Service to find a driver to your unknown device.

If it still persists, you can go to your device manager(Start Button/ right-click on Computer / Properties / Device Manager), find the device which has no known driver, right-click on it and select the option to disable it.

Comment: If you don't want to use your Bluetooth device for security reasons, you can still install the driver but then turn off the Bluetooth radio. This option will become available after you install the driver. That's what I do most of the time unless I decide to use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "quick & dirty" way to get rid of the "Found New Hardware Wizard" if it's popping up at every re-boot. I stumbled into this solution, even though when I searched a good bit for help, I never saw it.

[Now of course this assumes there is not a more appropriate solution, such as actually installing the hardware drivers, changing a software or BIOS setting, etc. But if you un-installed something and it left remnants, decided to quit-for-good an install mid-stream, things like that, then this is an easy non-technical way to get 'er done.]

Next time the Wizard pops up, go through the motions AS IF you were going to install the drivers.

At the first screen, pick "No, not this time" (as in don't check with Microsoft for the drivers).

At the second screen, pick "Install from a specific location (as in don't start searching the computer for the driver).

At the third screen, DE-select "Search removable media" and just below that, specify a folder on the computer that is EMPTY. This will cause the installation to immediately FAIL.

The fourth/failure screen – titled "Cannot Install This Software" – is the payoff. At the bottom of that screen, check off the box that says "Don't prompt me again to install this software." Click the Finish button.